# Bounds on algebraic equation

Tags: inequality

I have to show that:
$$
\frac{-\sqrt{(-\beta -\kappa  \sigma -1)^2-4 \beta}+\beta
 +\kappa  \sigma +1}{2 \beta } < 1
$$
I am not sure it is possible.
The constraints on the coefficients are: $0<\beta<1, \kappa>0, \sigma>0$.

My attempt:

\begin{align}
 &\frac{-\sqrt{(\beta + \kappa  \sigma +1)^2-4 \beta}+\beta
 +\kappa  \sigma +1}{2 \beta } \\
&<\frac{\sqrt{(\beta + \kappa  \sigma +1)^2-4 \beta}+\beta
 +\kappa  \sigma +1}{2 \beta } \\
&<\frac{\sqrt{(\beta + \kappa  \sigma +1)^2}+\beta
 +\kappa  \sigma +1}{2 \beta } \\
&< \frac{2(\beta
 +\kappa  \sigma +1)}{2 \beta }
\end{align}

But the last line is just above 1.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

\begin{align}
&& \frac{-\sqrt{(1+\kappa\sigma+\beta)^2 - 4\beta} + (1+\kappa\sigma+\beta)}{2\beta} &< 1\\
&\iff & -\sqrt{(1+\kappa\sigma+\beta)^2 - 4\beta} + (1+\kappa\sigma+\beta) &< 2\beta\\
&\iff & \underbrace{(1+\kappa\sigma+\beta) - 2\beta}_{= 1+\kappa\sigma-\beta > 1-\beta > 0} &< \sqrt{(1+\kappa\sigma+\beta)^2 - 4\beta}\\
&\iff & (1+\kappa\sigma+\beta)^2 - 4\beta(1+\kappa\sigma+\beta) + 4\beta^2 &< (1+\kappa\sigma+\beta)^2 - 4\beta\\
&\iff & 4\beta\bigl(1+\beta - (1+\kappa\sigma+\beta)\bigr) &< 0\\
&\iff & -4\beta\kappa\sigma &< 0,
\end{align}

which holds, since $\beta,\kappa,\sigma > 0$.

Comment: you can only square both sides of the given inequality if both sides are not negativ!

Comment: You mean, otherwise I don't have an equivalence. Yes, but since $0 < \beta < 1$, both sides are non-negative.

Comment: and why is $1+k\sigma-\beta$ non negative? aha since $1-\beta>0$ and $k\sigma>0$ ok, i hope that everyone saw it

Answer (score 0):

you must work backwards, we get
$-\sqrt{(-\beta-k\sigma-1)^2-4\beta}<\beta-k\sigma-1$
by multiplying with $2\beta>0$ and sorting the given variables.
my question:
can we say that $\beta-k\sigma-1>0$
if $\beta-k\sigma-1$ is positive, we have a true statement, in the other case we get by multipliying with $-1$ and squaring
$(-\beta-k\sigma-1)^2-4\beta>(\beta-k\sigma-1)^2$
should this be simplified?
finally we obtain $4\beta k\sigma>0$

Comment: How does this show the result? Ideally we wouldnt need $\beta - \kappa \sigma - 1 > 0$. Thanks.